# How to send a python variable to a perl subprocess

Tags: python, regex, perl

I am trying to use a perl regex to do somewhat complicated matching. In shell, it looks like:

```
cut -f6 file.txt | perl -ne 'chomp; $col=$_; $clipped = 0; foreach($col =~ m/(\d+)S/g){ $clipped +=$_;} print $col,"\t",$clipped,"\n";'
```

And this works, but the downstream parts of this script are taking too long, so I want to do this in python, instead.

For clarity, the perl line is finding the number before the character "S" in the sixth column of the file. There may be more than one "S", so it finds any digit before any "S" and stores that, then $clipped sums up those digits. If the column looked like 12S1I100M37S, then $clipped would total to be 49, for the 12S at the front and the 37S at the end. It ignores all other digits.

Back to python: using split()[5], I can get the sixth column to a variable, but I don't know how to pass that to subprocess.call('perl -ne etc').

Can someone suggest how I can do this or how I could use the python re module for the same type of matching?

Comment: Simpler: `perl -lane'$sum=0; $sum += $_ for $F[5] =~ /(\d+)S/g; print "$F[5]\t$sum"'`. (Add `-F\t` if tab-separated input.) Not sure why you think this would be faster in Python (unless the rest of the program is written in Python and you want to avoid the subprocess entirely, but you indicated you still want to use `perl`).

Comment: It's not this step that is faster in python - it is a downstream process that is, but I figure I may as well wrap them all together in a single script.

How does that pass a python variable to that perl line?

Comment: If you want a single script, why are you asking how to pass variables to other scripts?!

Comment: I call the perl line as a subprocess in python. I'm asking how to pass a variable into that subprocess.call('perl )

Comment: I know. That doesn't answer my question.

Comment: @ikegami has a good point OP - you should probably change your title, since what the title is asking and what you actually want to do are somewhat different (the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem))

Comment: @nietzschemouse  Answer to your question from the comment: the `-a` option breaks the line by spaces into `@F`, available in code.  If you want other than spaces to break by use `-F\t` (for tab).  The question is completely unclear to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is most likely a way more compact way to write this in Python. This is just my attempt, taking you very literally at your problem definition/boundary. Anyway, point being, using the `re` module is certainly an easy option if you want to stick with Python.

```
import re

def sum_str_digits(my_string):
    split_string = re.split(r'(\d+)', my_string)
    sums = 0
    for index, string_piece in enumerate(split_string):
        if string_piece == 'S':
            sums += int(split_string[index - 1])
    return sums

# For Python 2.x
print sum_str_digits(my_string='12S1I100M37S')

# Python 3.x
print(sum_str_digits(my_string='12S1I100M37S'))
```

Comment: I'm using python3.5 and needed to wrap the print statement in parentheses, but this is perfect, otherwise. Thanks!